# Bring up keyboard when cell pressed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is there a way to bring up the keyboard when I click on a cell in a UITableView?

I tried to find some way to connect one of the outlets of a cell to a declared IBAction but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a text field or something in the cell? If so, you can just call `[textField becomeFirstResponder]`. I'm not sure you can actually just pull up a keyboard without some text entry UI (using documented APIs, anyway).

Comment: I want to edit the text in the detail text label, so I want to make that my first responder, but how do I register that the user has pressed one of the cells? Is there a method to do this?

Comment: You can't directly edit the text in the detail text label with a keyboard like that. You need to subclass `UITableViewCell` and add a text field. To react to a user tapping a cell, you should override `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in your table view's delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do it but its somewhat complex:

- you put a UITextField in your cell, but position it out of view
- when you want the keyboard to appear, to edit some other UITextField in the cell, you make the UITextField that is in the cell offscreen the firstResponder
- now the tricky part - as the delegate messages start flowing - you essentially set the UITextField you WANT to have edited the first responder
- you get a flurry of delegate messages while this happens, so you need to do some work

In the end, the UITextField you want to get edited is the first responder. So, you can do what you want, but you have to spend some time working it all out.

Comment: Ah thanks mate, I get the idea now. I ended up adding a UILabel to my view which was hidden. Then, whenever a user pressed on any of the cells, it would begin to enter text into the hidden text box and whenever a key on the keyboard was pressed, it would update the detail text in the cell. Thanks!